# Is there a proper way to use template commands for object files in a makefile? (C++)

Tags: c++, makefile

Iam currently trying to create a template make command, which should create %.obj based on the cpp / header files.
I have currently the following files in my folder: main.cpp, sort.cpp, sort.h
This is the Make file iam trying to run:

```
CXX = cl
CXXFLAGS = /EHsc /nologo
MAIN_EXECUTABLE = main.exe

%.obj: %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /c $<

$(MAIN_EXECUTABLE): main.obj sort.obj
    link $(CXXFLAGS) $^ /OUT:$@

all: $(MAIN_EXECUTABLE)
.PHONY: all

clean:
    del *.obj
.PHONY: clean

distclean: clean
    del $(MAIN_EXECUTABLE)
.PHONY: distclean
```

Console output:
`` make: *** No rule to make target `main.obj', needed by `main.exe'. ``

So my question is, how do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the `%.h` to the pattern rule unless every single `.cpp` file you want to build with this pattern rule has an equivalent `.h` file.  Otherwise when make wants to build `main.obj` using this pattern rule it looks to see that `main.cpp` exists, and it does, then it looks to see that `main.h` exists, and it doesn't, so the pattern rule doesn't match.  Make keeps looking for other pattern rules that might build `main.obj` but there aren't any, so you get the error you see.

You have two choices: if virtually all of your `.cpp` files *do* have `.h` files, then you can create explicit rules for the few that don't like this:

```
%.obj : %.cpp %.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /c $<

main.obj : main.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /c $<
```

Or, you can leave off the `%.h` and declare the header prerequisites elsewhere like this:

```
%.obj : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /c $<

sort.obj : sort.h
```

This latter is the way makefiles are typically written, because it's almost unheard of that a `.cpp` file includes only one header file; usually you need to declare all the headers as prerequisites anyway.  Often this is done by adding [automated dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) facilities to your makefile.

I will say that you appear to be running on Windows, not a POSIX-based system like GNU/Linux or MacOS, so the automated dependency generation methods relying on capabilities of compilers such as GCC or Clang may not be available to you.